# Please help me install wifi driver

Tags: wireless, drivers

I am having trouble understanding how to install Asus wifi driver. [Here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/7399393/) are the instructions.

I have gotten the first 3 parts done correctly I believe.  Part 4 confuses me. I open the `os/linux/config.mk` file and I found where is states `HAS_WPA_SUPPLICANT`.  But the formatting is different.  It looks like this:

```
ifeq ($(HAS_WPA_SUPPLICANT),y)
WFLAGS += -DWPA_SUPPLICANT_SUPPORT
ifeq ($(HAS_NATIVE_WPA_SUPPLICANT_SUPPORT),y)
WFLAGS += -DNATIVE_WPA_SUPPLICANT_SUPPORT -DCREDENTIAL_STORE -DPROFILE_STORE
endif
endif
```

Can someone show me what I should have on those lines?  Also what directory should I be in when I enter make and make install?

Comment: What operative system are you using?

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: What is the device model? Also, where did you get the instructions from? Have you tried something, did you get any error?

Comment: It's an Asus USB-N53.  I got the instructions from the readme file on the provided disk.

Comment: Also, I"m not sure who edited my post but they left part of my comment/question attached to the build instructions in the paste bin.

Comment: I just spent half an hour on the phone trying to get in touch with asus support and they told me they don't provide support for operating systems.  I am asking for support on how to install the driver with the instructions they provide yet they cannot provide any support.  Asus support is non existant.  Please help.  This is a computer for my Mom and I am giving it to her this Saturday for Mothers day.

Comment: I really don't know why are you building a 2011 driver. You sure it's necessary? Edit your question and include the output of `sudo lspci -nnk`.

Comment: I'm afraid I have no idea what I am doing.  Asus provided me with a disk and I thought that's what I had to do to install the driver for it.  The asus usb works terrible slow and sometimes not at all so I was trying to install the Linux driver supplied on the cd.  I pulled that out and reinstalled the tp-link tl-wdn4800 which works much better than the asus usb one but it still runs at pretty slow bandwidths.  I found a site that mentions modifying ath9k.conf but I can't find that folder.  http://www.linux-hardware-guide.com/2012-11-01-tp-link-tl-wdn4800-wireless-n-dual-band-pcie-450mbps

Comment: I never got anything figured out on the Asus I originally posted the comment about but the TP-Link tl-wdn4800 is working normally now.  I appreciate everyone trying to help me out.  I am going to return the Asus.